# Get values in same row with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<tr>
                <td style="display:none;">
                    62
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color:Blue; cursor:pointer;" id="editLink">Edit</span> |
                    <span style="color:Blue; cursor:pointer;" id="detailsLink">Details</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Update Loan Data Component Rows
                </td>
                <td>
                    Daily: 22:00:00 PM
                </td>
                <td>
                    False
                </td>
            </tr>
```

So I have a JQuery click event binded to the two spans with `cursor:pointer`. When this is clicked, I want to be able to easily get the values within each of the table cells within this row, and set elements elsewhere on the page with these values.

How can I do this in JQuery?

P.S. I can Id the different cells, however then each row would have dupe Id's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `click` handler that is attached to the `<span>` elements:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
    alert( 'index ' + this.cellIndex + ': ' + $(this).text() );
});
```

- the [`jQuery()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) method to wrap the element that received the event (`this`) in a `jQuery` object
- the [`parent()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to get to the parent `<td>` of the `<span>` that was clicked.
- the [`siblings()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to get the sibling `<td>` elements of the one from the previous step
- the [`each()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over those `<td>` elements
- the [`text()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the text content of the current `<td>`

---

**EDIT:** Added the `cellIndex` property to the alert to indicate the index number of the `<td>` cell.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xjFGY/

Comment: @slandau: What do you mean? What sort of indicator do you want, other than the text content? Something like an index?

Comment: @slandau: I'll update. Basically each `<td>` element has a property that is its index in the row. The property is `cellIndex`, so you'd use `this.cellIndex`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("span").click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).parents("tr");
    alert( $tr.find("td").eq(0).html() ); // 1st td (62)
    alert( $tr.find("td").eq(2).html() ); // 3rd td
    alert( $tr.find("td").eq(3).html() ); // 4th td (date/time)
    alert( $tr.find("td").eq(4).html() ); // 5th td (bool)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to have unique ids. Use classes if you are going to have multiple.

```
$('span#editLink').click(function(){ 
$(this).parent().siblings().each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') == "frequency"){
        $('#other-frequency-field').html($(this).text());
    }
    else if($(this).attr('class') == "boolean"){
        $('#other-frequency-field').html($(this).text());
    }
}
```

With this you would have to add class values to the other table columns in order to recognize them. (I used boolean and frequency, just as examples).